# Django admin site with url parameters

Tags: python, django, django-admin, url-parameters

I have a Django project with several applications, and I want to add the Django admin site for one of these.

The problem I have is that the main `urls.py` file has

```
url(r'^tools/(\w+)/', include('tools.myapp.urls')),
```

and in my `myapp.urls` I have added

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

The problem is that the parent part of the url matching uses a parameter, which is usually passed in the template (that's the application name) like so

```
{% url "my_view_function" request.info.appname %}
```

But the default Django template obviously don't include that extra parameter, when calling

```
{% url 'admin:logout' %}
```

thus leading to a `NoReverseMatch` exception.

How can I have the admin site working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have admin run under any tools/whatever/admin URL, you can add this line *before* the `tools.myapp.urls` import in your main urls.py:

```
url(r'^tools/\w+/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: I need to have the `(\w+)` capture group of the URL because this is needed by other part of the site.

Comment: That's why you need to add this *before* the tools.myapp.urls, not instead of it. Your app will get the captured arg just fine, only admin won't.